# Не работает UPDATE PDO, не пойму почему?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть функция:

```
public static function badLids() {
  $db=Database::getConnection();
  $err="Ошибка обработки формы";
  $ok="Статус изменен";

if(isset($_POST['bad_lid']) && $_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']) {
  $id=$_POST['lidid'];
  $stat='4';
  $param=array(':stat'=>$stat, ':id'=>$id);
  $sql = "UPDATE lids SET stat_lids=:stat WHERE id_lids=:id";
  $sth=$db->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute($param);

  $_SESSION["ok"] = $ok;
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
} else {
  $_SESSION["error"] = $err;
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
      exit();
}
  }
```

Не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает, ошибок не дает, POST отправляется верный. Куда копать, куда смотреть? Подскажите, а то уже голова кипеть начинает.

Comment: это правильно, что вы проверяете наличие `bad_lid`, а используете `lidid` ?

Comment: bad_lid это название формы, а lidid это id поля в таблице

Comment: убедитесь, что эта ветка кода в if вообще выполняется. проверьте в конце результат выполнения `execute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Победил! Это все из-за не внимательности. Принимал $_POST по name формы. Переписал на name кнопки и все заработало